# How to filter by postal code range?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have to do an `ExecuteMultiple`, using a filter on the system-field `address1_postalcode`.

The condition of the filter is that the postal code should be in a range.

I used these two filters, but the result doesn't take into account the condition:

```
filter.Conditions.Add(
  new ConditionExpression(
    "address1_postalcode", 
    ConditionOperator.LessThan, 
    postalcodeMax
  )
);

filter.Conditions.Add(
  new ConditionExpression(
    "address1_postalcode", 
    ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, 
    postalcodeMin
  )
);
```

`postalcodeMin` and `postalcodeMax` are integers, and I know that `postalCode` field is string.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this kind of query on a Single line of text: you have to convert the value to a number.

A solution (off the top of my head) might be to create a custom numeric field, and fill it on-the-fly through a plugin on retrieve.

Comment: Plugin on `update` is probably a better option, or else the plugin will have to run on every record every time you run the query

Comment: @jasonscript that's another possible approach, sure, but then you'd have to somehow make it run on all existing records to fill the data, a on-retrieve plugin acts like a sort of calculated field and data is immediately available. I'm sure there are many more ways of solving this...

Answer (score 0):

In both FetchXML and Query Expression the greater than and less than operators work with strings.

While the sorting of strings and ints can be different, you can get started by using postalcodeMin.ToString() and postalcodeMax.ToString() in the conditions.

For reference, I successfully tested these conditions:

```
new ConditionExpression
{
    AttributeName = "address1_postalcode",
    Operator = ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual,
    Values = {"88888"}
},
new ConditionExpression
{
    AttributeName = "address1_postalcode",
    Operator = ConditionOperator.LessEqual,
    Values = {"99999" }
}
```

And this FetchXML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="owneridname" operator="gt" value="Smith" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```